# Hex number (0-15) and return ascii representation

Tags: python, string, ascii

For a cryptography application, I'm reading in strings that represent hexadecimal ( "36E06921", "27EA3C74" ) and need to xor them together and return a str of the result ("110A5555"). I'm able to xor char by char and get decimal result, but am having issues getting the ascii representation of the result. So, 0x3 xor 0x3 = 0x0. Whats the best way to get value 0 into ascii value 0x30?

Current attempt at implementation:

```
def xor_hexstrings(xs, ys):
    bin_x = binascii.unhexlify(xs)
    bin_y = binascii.unhexlify(ys)
    hex_str = ""
    for x,y in zip(xs, ys):         
        # fails, with error TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
        xored = binascii.b2a_hex(int(x, 16) ^ int(y, 16))
        hex_str += xored
return None
```

EDIT: Close, only issue is with zero. Following example shows recommended solution returns empty string for zero.

```
>>> hex(int('0', 16)).lstrip("0x")
''
>>> hex(int('1', 16)).lstrip("0x")
```

Comment: You can't just XOR the individual characters because they're not all in a contiguous range. You need to convert hex to int, xor, then convert int to hex again.

Comment: Example added showing im not just xoring ascii values.

Comment: To convert each digit back to hex, just use `hex(digit)` and strip off the `0x` at the beginning.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "slice" instead of "strip". Try `hex(0)[2:]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
x = "36E06921"
y = "27EA3C74"
z = ''.join([format((int(i,16)^int(j,16)),'X') for i,j in zip(x,y)])
print z
```

Output:

```
110A5555
```

Comment: No need to use `upper()` if you use a format string of `'X'` (upper case) instead of `'x'` (lower case).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need this:

```
>>> base10_int = int('0x0',16)
>>> base10_int_str = str(base10_int)
>>> base10_ascii_val = ord(base10_int_str)
>>> hex_ascii_val = hex(base10_ascii_val)
>>> hex_ascii_val
'0x30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting a pattern from Python 3 to the types available on Python 2: Use bytes-like objects to get natural `int` iteration:

```
import binascii 
from operator import xor 

def xor_hex(xs, ys): 
    xs = bytearray(binascii.unhexlify(xs))
    ys = bytearray(binascii.unhexlify(ys))
    return binascii.hexlify(bytearray(map(xor, xs, ys)))   # Stick a .upper() on this if it must produce uppercase hex

>>> print xor_hex( "36E06921", "27EA3C74" )
110a5555
```

In Python 3, it's simpler, since you can use `bytes` types directly instead of converting from Py2 `str` to `bytearray` to get `bytes`-like behavior:

```
def xor_hex(xs, ys): 
    xs = binascii.unhexlify(xs)
    ys = binascii.unhexlify(ys)
    return binascii.hexlify(bytes(map(xor, xs, ys)))
```

Although even that is fairly slow compared to what you can do with Python 3's `int.to_bytes` and `int.from_bytes` methods (which admittedly produce even uglier code).

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are asking here is to convert an integer into it's respective string representation. At least that is what the example 0x0 -> 0x30 would seem to suggest. If so, just cast to a string in python with the `str()` function.

```
>>> ord(str(0))
48
```

Just for reference 48 equals 0x30 and the [ord()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) function gives you integer representation of a character.

EDIT:
Check out the format function. Seems to have expected behavior!

```
>>> format(0x0, 'x')
'0'
```

Comment: That works for pure decimal numbers but not for hex.

Comment: This seems close to what I want, but say I have the xor result is 13, in hex 0xD. Would something similar be able to handle this?

Comment: so given int 13, you want hex 0xD? You can do hex(13)

Comment: used hex(x).lstrip("0x") and got something very close. Only issue is '0' isn't getting added to the string
>>>hex(0).lstrip("0x)
''